# ODP.Net OracleBulkCopy 'not a valid month' with a date field

Tags: oracle, datetime, copy, odp.net, bulk

First it is important to note that this error is occuring while importing a set of data using the OracleBulkCopy object in a WPF application with the data stored in a DataTable object.

In this table there is one column which is of type "Date" (oracle) and the corresponding type is DateTime? (nullable) in the WPF application.  However when setting up the DataTable for the OracleBulkCopy object I'm setting the data type of that column to DateTime (non-nullable) as nullable types are not permitted in the DataTable's DataColumn objects.

What is happeneing is that the data import works fine when all date values are null but as soon as I try an import with any actual dates I'm getting the error "Not a valid month" from the Oracle server.  Normally when something like this happens you can use "to_date" to specify how the date is supposed to be interpreted.

Using OracleBulkCopy this is not possible and should also not be necessary as the dates aren't strings but actual DateTime objects.

I have also tried using the data type Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate but this had the same result.

I have not been able to find any solution to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If anyone else is interested here's what I found out:  The DateTimes were being converted to string representations by use of the XML serializing and deserializing which was being used to send the data to a web service.  My less than elegant solution was to have a function on the receiving end to add another column (of type DateTime) and go through each row storing DateTime conversions of the strings into the new column then dumping the original column and renaming the new column to the name of the original.